# error while connecting to windows azure cloud's mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, windows, azure

i have uploaded my **PHP website** on **windows azure cloud**. The database i have used is **mysql**.
but while connectiong to remote mysql databse of azure i am getting an error.
initially it prompts for the password even though it is specified in the command itself. 
however whatever password i have used for the website, all of them are giving the following error.

---

**"****"Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

**C:\Documents and Settings\admin>mysql -h *datasource* -u *usename* -p *password* -D *database***

**Enter password:** **

**ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '***'@'%' **to database*** '*****'* **""**

---

please help.

Comment: There is no space between -p and password.  Also if you use -p but do not put in the password it will prompt for it.

Answer (score 0):

how big is the database you are deploying? The MySQL database which comes with your Windows Azure Web Site is 20MB. If your DB is larger than 20MB you will run into issues when attempting to push data to it.

Comment: The size is less than 20 MB for sure. Might be 5-6 MB max but i thought that i am not able to connect to their remote database server. any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart MySQL service. I had a lot of problems with putting data to tables on my Azure MySQL database (I couldn't even create new tables).

I just restarted MySQL Workbench and connected again to Azure's ClearDB database and now I am able to execute queries (inserts, selects, drops, deletes, etc.).